# Angular md-slider, передача данных в JS функцию

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть слайдер на angular'e:

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <md-slider flex min="0" max="260" ng-model="tax[id]" id="tax[id]" class></md-slider>
  <input flex type='number' ng-model="tax">
</div>
```

Подскажите, как данные слайдера (число) передать в JS функцию? Находящую в контролере? Мне необходимо выполнять действия при сдвиге слайдера.
Учитывая, что `ng-model="tax[id]"` `id="tax[id]"`, `id` случайные числа.

Comment: в какую функцию вы хотите передавать данные и в какой момент?

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понял что такое "учитывая, что ng-model="tax[id]" id="tax[id]", id случайные числа." поэтому:

1. сделать нормальный ng-model. пусть указывает на корректный объект внутри контроллера.

   ng-model='sliderVal'.
2. добавить ng-change директиву к слайдеру. в ng-change вызывать метод angular-контроллера.

   ng-change='onSliderChange()'
3. в методе данные слайдера будут доступны в sliderVal.

   console.log($scope.sliderVal);

Comment: Выдаёт undefined.